# Calling selector from protocol extension

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, protocol-extension

I'm building simple theme engine and would like have an extension which adds `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to `UIViewController`

Here is my code:

```
protocol Themeable {
    func themeDidUpdate(currentTheme: Theme) -> Void
}

extension Themeable where Self: UIViewController {
    func switchCurrentTheme() {
        Theme.switchTheme()
        themeDidUpdate(Theme.currentTheme)
    }

    func addSwitchThemeGestureRecognizer() {
        let gestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(Self.switchCurrentTheme))
        gestureRecognizer.direction = .Down
        gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

Of course compiler can't find `#selector(Self.switchCurrentTheme)` as it isn't exposed via `@objc` directive. Is it possible to add this behaviour to my extension?

**UPDATE:** `Theme` is a Swift enum, so I can't add `@objc` in front of `Themeable` protocol

Answer (score 22):

The cleanest, working solution I could come up with was to define a private extension on `UIViewController` with the method in question. By limiting the scope to `private`, access to this method is isolated to within the source file where the protocol is defined in. Here's what it looks like:

```
protocol Themeable {
    func themeDidUpdate(currentTheme: Theme) -> Void
}

fileprivate extension UIViewController {
    @objc func switchCurrentTheme() {
        guard let themeableSelf = self as? Themeable else {
            return
        }

        Theme.switchTheme()
        themeableSelf.themeDidUpdate(Theme.currentTheme)
    }
}

extension Themeable where Self: UIViewController {
    func addSwitchThemeGestureRecognizer() {
        let gestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(switchCurrentTheme))
        gestureRecognizer.direction = .Down
        gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Worked like a charm. :) In Swift 3, the private extension of UIViewController now needs to be fileprivate instead. Also, the switchCurrentTheme function should be fileprivate instead of internal.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. May be not the perfect one, but it works. 
As I can't define `Themeable` protocol as `@objc` because it uses Swift-only `enum` I decided to move method I want to call to "parent" protocol and define this protocol as `@objc`. It seems like it works but I don't really like it to be honest...

```
@objc protocol ThemeSwitcher {
    func switchCurrentTheme()
}

protocol Themeable: ThemeSwitcher {
    func themeDidUpdate(currentTheme: Theme) -> Void
}

extension Themeable where Self: UIViewController {
    func switchCurrentTheme() {
        Theme.switchTheme()
        themeDidUpdate(Theme.currentTheme)
    }

    func addSwitchThemeGestureRecognizer() {
        let gestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(switchCurrentTheme))
        gestureRecognizer.direction = .Down
        gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work as I can't apply `@objc` to my `ViewController` which implements `Themeable` protocol..

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a wrapper to let you call your non-@objc function from an @objc one?

```
@objc class Wrapper: NSObject {
    let themeable: Themeable

    init(themeable: Themeable) {
        self.themeable = themeable
    }

    func switchCurrentTheme() {
        Theme.switchTheme()
        themeable.themeDidUpdate(Theme.currentTheme)
    }
}

protocol Themeable {
    func themeDidUpdate(currentTheme: Theme) -> Void
}

extension Themeable where Self: UIViewController {
    func addSwitchThemeGestureRecognizer() {
        let wrapper = Wrapper(themeable: self)
        let gestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: wrapper, action:#selector(Wrapper.switchCurrentTheme))
        gestureRecognizer.direction = .Down
        gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but couldn't get it to work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar use-case, you can call a method through a selector without using @objc as in swift by using the dynamic keyword. By doing so, you are instructing the compiler to use dynamic dispatch implicitly.

```
import UIKit

protocol Refreshable: class {

    dynamic func refreshTableData()

    var tableView: UITableView! {get set}
}

extension Refreshable where Self: UIViewController {

    func addRefreshControl() {
        tableView.insertSubview(refreshControl, at: 0)
    }

    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl {
        get {
            let tmpAddress = String(format: "%p", unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self))
            if let control = _refreshControl[tmpAddress] as? UIRefreshControl {
                return control
            } else {
                let control = UIRefreshControl()
                control.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("refreshTableData")), for: .valueChanged)
                _refreshControl[tmpAddress] = control
                return control
            }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate var _refreshControl = [String: AnyObject]()

class ViewController: UIViewController: Refreshable {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            addRefreshControl()
        }
    }

    func refreshTableData() {
        // Perform some stuff
    }
}
```